# How to replace comma with dash using python pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas, replace

I have a file like this:

```
name|count_dic
name1 |{'x1':123,'x2,bv.':435,'x3':4}
name2|{'x2,bv.':435,'x5':98}
etc.
```

I am trying to load the data into a dataframe and count the number of keys in in the count_dic. The problem is that the dic items are separated with comma and also some of the keys contain comma. I am looking for a way to be able to replace commas in the key with '-' and then be able to separate different key,value pairs in the count_dic.something like this:

```
name|count_dic
name1 |{'x1':123,'x2-bv.':435,'x3':4}
name2|{'x2-bv.':435,'x5':98}
etc.
```

This is what I have done.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file' ,names = ['name','count_dic'],delimiter='|')
data = json.loads(df.count_dic)
```

and I get the following error:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'Series'
```

Does any body have any suggestions?

Comment: Your title doesn't describe the actual problem -- edit it so other people will find what they're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` as a converter for loading the dataframe, as it appears you have data that's more Python `dict`-like... JSON uses double quotes - eg:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

df = pd.read_csv('file', delimiter='|', converters={'count_dic': ast.literal_eval})
```

Gives you a DF of:

```
    name                            count_dic
0  name1  {'x2,bv.': 435, 'x3': 4, 'x1': 123}
1  name2            {'x5': 98, 'x2,bv.': 435}
```

Since `count_dic` is actually a `dict`, then you can apply `len` to get the number of keys, eg:

```
df.count_dic.apply(len)
```

Results in:

```
0    3
1    2
Name: count_dic, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. did not know about ast.literal, so it can be use to convert any string to python recognized values like , list, or dict , or tuple etc? right?

Comment: @UserYmY as long as they're valid syntactically - see https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval for further info.

Comment: @ Jon Clements , Thanks. Is there a way that I can index keys and values of the count_dic now with this method?

Comment: @UserYmY do you mean something like: `df.iloc[0].count_dic['x1']` (which gives you 123) - although it looks like you should probably make `name` the actual index for your DF.

Comment: Yeah but I mean more general, so I can add up all of the values in the dictionary of all rows.

Comment: @UserYmY you mean something like `df.count_dic.apply(lambda L: sum(L.values()))` ? (you can add a `.sum()` to the end of that to get the grand total)

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I need. But .sum() is not working

Answer (score 1):

Once `df` is defined as above:

```
# get a value to play around with
td = df.iloc[0].count_dic
td
# that looks like a dict definition... evaluate it?
eval(td)
eval(td).keys() #yup!
#apply to the whole df
df.count_dic = map(eval, df.count_dic)

#and a hint towards your key-counting
map(lambda i: i.keys(), df.count_dic)
```