# Python Pandas: How can I sum all of the values of a dictionary in a column of my dataframe?

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, lambda, sum

Here is my dataframe:

```
    name                            count_dic
0  name1  {'x2,bv.': 435, 'x3': 4, 'x1': 123}
1  name2            {'x5': 98, 'x2,bv.': 435}
```

and I want to sum up all of the value of the dic in 'count_dic' column to have something like this:

```
    name                            count_dic   sum_vals
0  name1  {'x2,bv.': 435, 'x3': 4, 'x1': 123}    562
1  name2            {'x5': 98, 'x2,bv.': 435}    533
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
df_map.count_dic.apply(lambda L: sum(L.values())).sum()
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_values' and 'dict_values'
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note: Your dataframe structure looks a bit odd to me, and probably will perform quite suboptimally if the dataset gets big.*

---

In any case your code appears well-formed [Tested on python 2.7.8 and 3.4.1]

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['name','count_dic'])
 df.loc[0] = ['name0',{'x2,bv.': 435, 'x3': 4, 'x1': 123}]
 df.loc[1] = ['name1',{'x5': 98, 'x2,bv.': 435}]

 df.count_dic.apply(lambda x : sum(x.values())).sum()

       1095
```

and if you want the values by row

```
 df.count_dic.apply(lambda x : sum(x.values()))

        0    562
        1    533
    Name: count_dic, dtype: int64
```

---

The use had a further specific problem related to the type of the variables involved which were not int and an explicit cast was needed.

```
 df.count_dic.apply(lambda x : sum([int(y) for y in x.values())])
```

Comment: @Acrobe, I am using the same code, and I am getting the error I described above but I cannot find why. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @UserYmY, which python version?, do you get something meaningful with `df.count_dic.apply(lambda x : x.values())` ?

Comment: I am using ipython on Python 3

Comment: which python kernel version underneath? 2.7 or 3.x?

Comment: I am using Python 3.x

Comment: Calling d.keys() will return a dictionary view object. It supports operations like membership test and iteration, but its contents are not independent of the original dictionary – it is only a view.

Comment: I have the same behavior both with python 2.7 and 3.x. Try with a fresh kernel and see if it works. Maybe you have some dirty variable in memory.
Try also the very same code of this reply in a fresh kernel

Comment: is not working still. Can it be because of this? Because I have converted my column to dictionary using this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728448/how-to-replace-comma-with-dash-using-python-pandas?noredirect=1#comment47591259_29728448

Comment: Does work for me on python 2.x but not on my ipython with python 3.x. Strange!

Comment: and even with python 2 I get sum of all values, not sum of values per row, which is what I want.

Comment: oh to do it by row you just have to avoid the last sum call. See modified reply.

Comment: maybe you need an explicit cast:  `df.count_dic.apply(lambda x : sum([int(y) for y in x.values())])`

Comment: Exactly. Thanks alot That solved it.  pppfff the values where not int but other types right?

Comment: Yep.. it means that they were strings or something. I'll finally modify the answer.

Comment: @UserYmY. I finally modified the reply. If you are satisfied would you please accept it?

Comment: Regarding the error, I think they were dict.values and you can't add them together with + .  You get a similar error when you do this df.loc[0,"count_dic"] + df.loc[0,"count_dic"]

Comment: @Acrobe and Bob Haffner Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

**Step1:** Make sure that while reading the data the column has proper data type i.e. <key, value>. If it has been read as string first convert it into dict format.

```
import ast
dict_col_data=[]
for row in df["test_col"]:
  dict_col_data.append(ast.literal_eval(row))
df["test_col_dict"]=dict_col_data
```

**Step 2:** Now calculate the sum for every row by explicitly declaring the dtype to avoid any mismatch while reading.

```
df.test_col_dict.apply(lambda x :sum([int(y) for y in x.values()]) )
```